# Arduino Serial Return Weird Numbers + Trouble converting char array to int C++

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port, strtok

I'm working on a project with this code:

```
#include <string.h>
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{

if (Serial.available()) {
String input = String(Serial.read());
Serial.println("original: " + input);
char inputarray[100];
input.toCharArray(inputarray, 100);
  char *message = inputarray;
  char* num;


  num = strtok(message, ":");
  String numstr(num);
Serial.println(numstr);


  num = strtok(NULL, ":");
 String numstr2(num);
Serial.println(numstr);


}

delay(500);

}
```

It's supposed to read input from the Serial port and parse it so that an input of "10:15:20" would return 3 outputs, "10", "15", and "20".

My issue is that when I send the string "10:15:20" in the Serial terminal, it returns this:

```
original: 49
49
49
original: 48
48
48
original: 58
58
58
original: 49
49
49
original: 53
53
53
original: 58
58
58
original: 50
50
50
original: 48
48
48
```

Now, I'm really confused. I tried entering a single number, say, '1' into the serial, and it returns this:

```
original: 49
49
49
```

So, not only does it think '1' is '49', when I enter something like "10:15:20" it loops the program 8 times while using that statement as 'input'.

Why is this happening? Is there something wrong with my code, or is it something wrong with the arduino/arduino software?

Any Help is greatly appreciated!!!!

-Gabriel

**EDIT: Thanks to Mitch Wheat for bringing to my attention that the serial terminal was outputting my 'numstr' variable as ASCII.... Now I'm just wondering:**

1. How do I convert char array 'num' to an int so that I can see the correct output in the Serial Monitor
2. It doesn't seem as if I'm getting the right output in my serial monitor.... "10:15" doesn't seem to return two statements "10" and "15"...

---

I also tried to print the output using atoi() like this:

```
num = strtok(message, ":");
    Serial.println(atoi(num));
```

But to no avail... (I'm not sure if I was using atoi correctly, so this may be irrelevant but I'll add it anways.

---

**BIG EDIT:**

Ok. So, thanks to Alphonsos_Pangas, I was able to get it to print correctly and verified that my strtok() was working correctly.

Now, however, my issue is when I try to convert the string that I got from strtok(); to an int, I get an error. I've been using this code:

```
#include <string.h>

String data[4];

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{

if (Serial.available()) {

   String input = String(Serial.readStringUntil((char)13));
   Serial.println("original: " + input);
   //Serial.println(atoi(input.c_str()));
  // Serial.println(strtok(input.c_str(), ":"));

  data[0] = ((char*)strtok((char*)input.c_str(), ":"));
  Serial.println(data[0]);

  int testint = data[0].toInt;

  data[1] = (strtok(NULL, ":"));
  Serial.println(data[1]);

  data[2] = (strtok(NULL, ":"));
  Serial.println(data[2]);

  data[3] = (strtok(NULL, ":"));
  Serial.println(data[3]);
}

delay(500);
Serial.println("end");
}
```

It all works correctly except this line:

```
 int testint = data[0].toInt;
```

It's supposed to convert the String (The number that I put in first) to an int, but when I try to compile it it says this:

```
cannot convert 'String::toInt' from type 'long int (String::)()const' to type 'int'
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: "So, not only does it think '1' is '49'"  : ascii '1' IS 49

Comment: @MitchWheat So does that mean my code IS parsing the two number correctly, it's just not outputting in the same language that I inputted?

Comment: "it's just not outputting in the same language that I inputted?" - it has nothing to do with language: it's representation. chars are encoded ints

Comment: @MitchWheat So how do I go about converting my char array to an int? I tried doing Serial.println(atoi(num)); because I thought that atoi converts char arrays to ints, but it says: "invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]" when I try to upload it to the board, which makes it seem like atoi is supposed to convert an int to a char array....?

Comment: hint: atoi converts a string to an integer...http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: @MitchWheat I can't seem to find a way to do this that doesn't give me errors.... Also, on many forums people have said that atoi() does do what I want it to do.... Why does it work for them but not for me? Example of one of those sites: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=44151.0        Also, is my 'num' variable a char array or something else?

Comment: @GabrielRuoff Update your code with your `atoi()` attempt (or add to the end of your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Arduino installed in the PC I 'm using right now, so I hope I get this right...

For one thing, your code is way more complex than necessary
You can simplify

```
num = strtok(message, ":");
String numstr(num);
Serial.println(numstr);

num = strtok(NULL, ":");
String numstr2(num);
Serial.println(numstr);
```

as

```
Serial.println(strtok(input.c_str(), ":"));
Serial.println(strtok(NULL, ":"));
```

Also,

```
String input = String(Serial.Serial.readStringUntil((char)13));
```

Will probably be closer to what you want (assuming your input strings are terminated with CR)

```
if (Serial.available()) {
   String input = String(Serial.Serial.readStringUntil((char)13));
   Serial.println("original: " + input);
   Serial.println(atoi(input.c_str()) ;
   Serial.println(strtok(input.c_str(), ":"));
   Serial.println(strtok(NULL, ":"));
}
```

Will hopefully do what you want.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it and get back to you

Comment: Ok, so I tried it and it gave me this error: "invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]" on this line: "Serial.println(strtok(input.c_str(), ":"));" Also, what is CR? Pardon the dumb question as I am a noob to these functions and this code....

Comment: CR stands for "carriage return", a character whose ASCII code is 13 and which is frequently used as a line terminator. Alternatively you should check for (char)10 (LF - Line Feed) or char(0) (used to terminate strings in C).

Comment: OK thanks...  Now I'm just wondering why is it giving me the invalid conversion error?

Comment: Regarding the error, please try the following to see if they pass: Serial.println((char*)strtok(input.c_str(), ":")) ; OR Serial.println(strtok((char*)input.c_str(), ":")) ; OR Serial.println((char*)strtok((char*)input.c_str(), ":")) ;

Comment: Thanks!! It worked! Now, I just have one last issue that's described in my recent edit. It should be a simple fix, I just don't know what's wrong.....

Comment: That's a simple one: you forgot the parentheses: int testint = data[0].toInt() ;

Comment: However, for this to work, data[0] must be a String. For this, you probably need the following: data[0] = String(strtok((char*)input.c_str(), ":")); (I don't know if an implicit conversion works in this case).

Comment: Alright, so I've fixed it. Now I just have this question... It's a little off of the topic but I want to map the values like this: Serial.println("Mapped: " + map(long(data[0].toInt()), 0, 235, 900, 1920)); I thought that map() outputs an int, but in the serial window it displays symbols �'s. So how do I get map() to output an int? I tried Serial.println("Mapped: " + map(long(data[0].toInt()), 0, 235, 900, 1920).toInt()); but that didn't work either...

Comment: As a general advice, this should be a new question (in the sense than it will be difficult for subsequent readers to find it here, in case others have a similar problem. That said, have you tried printing with two separate calls, like Serial.print("Mapped: ") ; Serial.println(map(long(data[0].toInt()), 0, 235, 900, 1920).toInt()); ?

Comment: Explanation: In C / C++, the value of an array of characters (like "Mapped: ") is just a number (more accurately, a pointer to character, i.e. a number representing the position in memory of the first character) When you add to this a number, you are simply pointing to a subsequent position. i.e. Serial.println("This is a string"+5) ; will print "is a string".

Comment: Ok... It seems to be working. Thanks for all your help! However, I'm having some issues with this project that don't specifically pertain to this question... There's a couple issues, so I don't want to have to make like 4 questions.. Where should I go for help?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking 4 questions, as long as the issues are separate. Just make sure you do some research beforehand to check if your questions have been asked and replied before.